# Terminology for exchanging one piece of signed information for another

Tags: cryptography, digital-signature

Applications that use cryptographically signed information for multiple purposes have the risk that one piece of signed information can be exchanged with another. When you use JWTs as session tokens, and you use JWTs as password reset tokens, the password reset tokens should not be valid as session tokens. So a piece of signed information should be valid for only a specific purpose.

I am looking how to describe this more succintly, to [include this in the ASVS](https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/issues/872). What is the name of this attack?

I found one example: [Missing Required Cryptographic Step Leading to Sensitive Information Disclosure in TYPO3 CMS · CVE-2020-15098 · GitHub Advisory Database](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-m5vr-3m74-jwxp). Are there any more example?

The purpose of the signed data can be set using the "additional data" in AEAD ciphers, and partially in the audience field in a JWT. Is there a better name for such a field?

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of the signed data can be set using the "additional data" in AEAD ciphers, and partially in the audience field in a JWT. Is there a better name for such a field?

This mechanism is sometimes called **domain separation**.

In [SP 800-185, SHA-3 Derived Functions: cSHAKE, KMAC, TupleHash, ParallelHash | CSRC](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-185/final):

> Domain Separation - For a function, a partitioning of the inputs to different application domains so that no input is assigned to more than one domain.

cSHAKE has a "Customization String" for this purpose:

> The cSHAKE function also includes an input string (S) to allow users
> to customize their use of the function. For example, someone using
> cSHAKE128 to compute a key fingerprint (the hash value for a public
> key) might use:
>
> ```
> cSHAKE128(public_key, 256, "", "key fingerprint"),
> ```
>
> where "key fingerprint" is a customization string S.

[key derivation - What is meant by domain separation in the context of KDF? - Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66969/what-is-meant-by-domain-separation-in-the-context-of-kdf)

[This document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-saag-context-labels-00) uses "Context Labels" for domain separation.

[This document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve/16/) obtains domain separation using "domain separation tags".

[The Kyber paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) simply calls this parameter the "domain separator".

[RFC8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032) specifies Ed25519ctx with a "context input".

[ORCHID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7343.txt) uses a "Context Identifier", but that is a randomly generated value, not a static string.

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of the signed data can be set using the "additional data" in AEAD ciphers, and partially in the audience field in a JWT. Is there a better name for such a field?

In the context of block ciphers, this is sometimes called the **tweak**. A [tweakable block cipher](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/what-is-a-tweakable-block-cipher) gives a different permutation for a different tweak value. An exposed tweak value does not compromise security. It can for instance be used to encrypt session tokens and password resets with the same key, but a different tweak, to avoid exchanging one for the other.